# Method not allowed (http error 405) , wcf , rest service , post method

Tags: c#, ajax, rest, wcf, post

I am trying to call post method which is implemented in wcf , from html , ajax script.
I am able to invoke from postman . I tried google , stackoverflow previous questions , but none of them helped me.

My web.config from wcf :

```
  <standardEndpoints>
      <webScriptEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webScriptEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>

<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,DELETE,HEAD,PUT,OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

The following is my ajax call in html

```
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:8078/SportsClubDefault.svc/Validate",
      data: st,
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       processData:true,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
          // Play with response returned in JSON format
            alert('Login success');
      },
       error: function (xhr) {
             alert('Login failed');
         }
     });
```

The following is the image from postman
[image]

The following is the image of html console 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a CORS issue, You can enable cors by creating a global.asax file on wcf service,

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, DELETE");

        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: But my wcf service dont have global.asax file .

Comment: sorry for dumb question as I am new to c# . is adding a new file (global.asax ) just fine ?

Comment: yes, that should be fine. if you have any issue check this https://gist.github.com/sajeetharan/16067e5b94f1aa629f2e356b6432fcd9